# Conditional call to webApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a collection of `actors` in a db that I can get with the following call to an webApi:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/actors");
```

This triggers the following method on my webapi-controller:

```
 // GET: api/Actors
    public IQueryable<Actor> GetActors()
    {
        return db.Actors;
    }
```

Now lets say that im interseted in fetching all the Actors who have won an oscar. A call directly to the DB without the webapi could look something like this:

```
return db.actors.where(o=>o.OscarWinner==true);
```

But how can a similar call be made using the webApi?
Is the Api restricted to only let me fetch either All actors:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/actors");
```

or one specific actor:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/actors/1");
```

This must be a common request I would think, being able to get a list of objects based on some condition?

EDIT:

```
 public IQueryable<Actor> GetUsers(int CountrId)
    {
        var list = db.Actors.Where(o => o.CountryId == CountryId);
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from Professional ASP.NET MVC 4 book

> To accept incoming values from the request, you can put parameters on you action and just like MVC, the Web API framework will automatically provide values for those action parameters. Unlike MVC, there is a strong line drawn between values from the HTTP body and values taken from other places (like from the URI).
>   By default, Web API will assume that parameters which are simple types (that is the intrinsic types, strings, dates, times, and anything with a type converter from strings) are taken from non-body values, and complex types (everything else) are taken from the body. There is an additional restriction as well: Only a single value can come from the body, and that value must represent the entirety of the body.

So you have two options. If you'd like to have only simple filter, it's enough to take it from query string. Better option would be to write a class, which will map its attributes from JSON request body. I'm going to provide an example, how I mapped filter data from query string, because I wanted to allow my users to query data through query string. I wrote a filter class binded with ModelBinder.

### 1. Query string

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/actors/?oscarWinner=true");
```

coresponding action method

```
// GET: api/Actors
public IQueryable<Actor> GetActors(bool oscarWinner = false)
{
    return db.Actors.Where(actor=>actor.OscarWinner == oscarWinner);
}
```

### 2. ModelBinder

Condition Filter Class

```
/// <summary>
/// Condition Filter
/// </summary>
public class ConditionFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Oscar Winner
    /// </summary>
    public bool? OscarWinner { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Page you want to get. Counting from 0.
    /// </summary>
    public int? Page { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Number of jobs on page. Default page size 1000.
    /// </summary>
    public int? PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

Condition Filter Binder

```
public class ConditionFilterBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof (ConditionFilter))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (val == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(val.RawValue.ToString());

        var conditionFilter = new ConditionFilter
        {
            Page = queryString.GetValueFromQueryString<int>("page"), 
            PageSize = queryString.GetValueFromQueryString<int>("pageSize"),
            OscarWinner = queryString.GetValueFromQueryString<bool>("oscarWinner")
         };

         bindingContext.Model = conditionFilter;

         return true;
         }
    }
}
```

and use it with your action method

```
public List<Actor> GetActors([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(ConditionFilterBinder))] ConditionFilter conditionFilter = null)
{
    //just to be sure, that we will not take some huge amount of data from database
    const int MAX_ACTOR_COUNT = 1000;
    var page = 0;
    var pageSize = MAX_ACTOR_COUNT;
    var actors = db.Actors;
    if (conditionFilter != null)
    {
        if(conditionFilter.OscarWinner.HasValue && conditionFilter.OscarWinner.Value)
        {
            actors = actors.Where(actor => actor.OscarWinner)
        }
        if (conditionFilter.Page.HasValue)
        {
            page = conditionFilter.Page.Value;
        }

        if (conditionFilter.PageSize.HasValue)
        {
            pageSize = conditionFilter.PageSize.Value > MAX_ACTOR_COUNT ? MAX_ACTOR_COUNT : conditionFilter.PageSize.Value;
        }
    }
    return actors.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
}
```

with this implementation you can call your action method for example like this

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/actors?oscarWinner=true&page=3&pageSize=100");
```

just to be complete, this is my `GetValueFromQueryString` helper class

```
/// <summary>
/// Extension method for name value collection
/// </summary>
public static class NameValueCollectionExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get typed value from query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queryString"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T? GetValueFromQueryString<T>(this NameValueCollection queryString, string value) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (queryString[value] != null)
        {
            var thisType = default(T);
            var typeCode = thisType.GetTypeCode();

            switch (typeCode)
            {
                case TypeCode.Boolean:
                    {
                        bool queryStringValue;
                        if (bool.TryParse(queryString[value], out queryStringValue))
                        {
                            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(queryStringValue, typeCode);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case TypeCode.Int32:
                case TypeCode.Int64:
                    {
                        if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
                        {
                            var numberValue = queryString.GetValueFromQueryString<int>(value);
                            if (numberValue.HasValue && Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), numberValue.Value))
                            {
                                return (T)(object)numberValue;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                T queryStringValueForEnum;
                                if (Enum.TryParse(queryString[value], true, out queryStringValueForEnum))
                                {
                                    return queryStringValueForEnum;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        int queryStringValue;
                        if (int.TryParse(queryString[value], out queryStringValue))
                        {
                            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(queryStringValue, typeCode);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case TypeCode.DateTime:
                    {
                        DateTime queryStringValue;
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(queryString[value], out queryStringValue))
                        {
                            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(queryStringValue, typeCode);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get string value from query string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="queryString"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string GetValueFromQueryString(this NameValueCollection queryString, string value)
    {
        return queryString[value];
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, thank you!
Let say my actors-table has a foreign-key representing a country. I would like to be able to pass that Int to my query-string. I updated my question with how the db-call could look like. Thank you

Comment: In that case you are done already.
You should call your API method like this 


`var response = await client.GetAsync("api/actors/?countrId=42");`

Comment: Aha Perfect! 
Thank you